# trying to install spyder into working environment but conda shows OpenSSL not installed

Tags: spyder, anaconda3

I am just starting with Anaconda 3 on a windows 11 machine.
I am able to install packages into the base environment with no problems.
But when I try to install Spyder into an environment that I created I get the error message
that OpenSSL appears to be unavailable on this machine.
I used Anaconda navigator to verify that the OpenSSL package is installed in the environment that I created.

I verified that OpenSSL is installed in both the base environment and my working environment